# Open/Save data from JTable with ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, swing, jtable, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I have a PhoneBook application which stores data into an arraylist from a JTable.
In GUI i have Save and Open buttons which suppose to save and open the data as an file object. 
I've managed to create a file which contains the information from the arraylist.

UPDATE: How can't make it load the info back to the JTable?

I'm new at Java and i will apreciate your patience and your help. Anticipated thanks!

Here's the code:

In the **model** class (extends AbstractTableModel)

```
public void saveContact() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    f.createNewFile();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
    oos.writeObject(listaContacte); // listaContacte is the arraylist
    System.out.println("S-a salvat");
}

public void loadContact() throws IOException {
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
    try {
        ois.readObject();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CarteDeTelefon.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.out.println("s-a incarcat ");
}
}
```

In the **GUI**

```
   private void saveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    try {
        model.saveContact();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}   

    private void openActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    if (evt.getSource() == open) {
    int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(GUI.this);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
       try {
        model.loadContact();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GUI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);}
    } 
    }     
}
```

UPDATE:

```
public void loadContact() throws IOException {
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
            try {
                List<Abonat> obiect = (List<Abonat>) ois.readObject(); // "variable `obiect` is not used" 
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(CarteDeTelefon.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        System.out.println("s-a incarcat ");

}
```

Comment: As always, break any big problem into much smaller sub problems, and then try to solve each problem in isolation. As it is, I fear that your question is way too broad, that it should in fact be several separate questions (but not asked all at once).

Comment: Also, you'll want to accept Camickr's answer to your [question from yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24439536/add-user-input-data-to-an-arraylist-and-display-it-into-a-jtable-using-custom-a).

Comment: Use a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) to handle periodic tasks having uncertain latency.

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels thanks for suggestions, i've updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does nothing useful:

```
ois.readObject();
```

And is equivalent to this code:

```
3 + 5;
```

Yes, this is valid Java, but you're throwing out the result without doing anything with it. For my trivial example, I'd assign the result from the addition to an int variable:

```
int result = 3 + 5;
// now I can print out the result, or use it elsewhere.
```

For your code, you need to assign what was read in into a variable, and that variable needs to be the same type as your listaContacte variable. You will need to cast the result returned from the method to that type as well.

```
SomeType someVar = (SomeType) ois.readObject; // catch relevant exceptions
// here create my new table model with someVar.
```

Comment: if i try List<Abonat> obiect = (List<Abonat>) ois.readObject(); it says that "obiect" is not used, which is true, but were should i use it?

Comment: @Zodrak: If you've tried something and it isn't working, then you should post your attempt as an edit to your question, showing your new code (but not deleting the old code or text) at the bottom, and describing any and all issues the code is having. If you're getting error messages or exceptions, then post the actual and complete message. Don't try to paraphrase the message as you're liable to leave out critical information if you do.

Comment: @Zodrak: and I don't see how we can tell you how to use your obiect since this would depend much on code you've not shown us. Think of how would you create a new table model with this variable, and then do so. Then set your JTable with this model.

Comment: not entirely. i cannot figure how to use that variable, since i have the model, the table, the array done.

Comment: @Zodrak: Again, you must use that variable to construct your model. The how will depend on your code.